# How to await a function until a pop up window is closed in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app with a form and when the user wishes to submit a form they may need to be presented with a pop up. I'd like to be able to create a function that (upon submit) will `await` for the pop up to be closed before progressing through the rest of the function code.

Pseudo-code below:

```
const onSubmit = useCallback(async (data) => {
    // START FORM CODE
    //...

    // display a pop up that pauses this `onSubmit` code until it is closed
    // while subsequently returning a success boolean

    const isValid = await onShowPopUp(true)

    //...
    // END FORM CODE
}, [])

return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input name="test" />
    </form>
)
```

My first attempt was to have the `onShowPopUp` return a promise and inside that promise is a while loop that runs while the `onShowPopUp` argument is true:

```
const onShowPopUp = useCallback(async (show: boolean) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        setShowPopUp(show) // useState hook that controls if popup is visible
        while (show) {
            console.log('waiting...')
            await sleep(1000)
        }
        resolve(true)
    })
}, [])
```

This kind of works as it pauses progression, but if the `onShowPopUp` is called again with a `false` argument (which would cause the the pop up to close), it doesn't cancel the previous `while` loop. Which I suppose makes sense, due to a react re-render?

What's the preferred method for a scenario like this using ReactJS/Javascript?

Thanks

---

FWIW, the pop up, is a Material UI [Drawer](https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/) element that looks something like this:

```
// reminder that showPopUp/setShowPopUp is a useState boolean
<Drawer open={showPopUp} />
```

Comment: have you worked on the `onClose` event of the `Drawer`?

Comment: @lastr2d2 I am aware of it yes, but how would defining that property prevent the progress on my function logic though

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if we introduce something like `deferred`.

```
// Copied from https://github.com/seangenabe/es6-deferred/blob/master/deferred.js
var Deferred = function() {
  this.promise = new Promise((function(resolve, reject) {
    this.resolve = resolve;
    this.reject = reject;
  }).bind(this));
  
  this.then = this.promise.then.bind(this.promise);
  this.catch = this.promise.catch.bind(this.promise);
};
```

It can be converted to a custom react hook `useDeferred`. (actually there is already a package here https://github.com/skt-t1-byungi/use-deferred)

With this, you can create a deferred object that can be accessed by both functions, `await` it in your `onShowPopUp`, and `resolve` it in `onClose`.

Here is an example without the Material UI library/React but I believe it's the same idea.

```js
var Deferred = function() {
  this.promise = new Promise((function(resolve, reject) {
    this.resolve = resolve;
    this.reject = reject;
  }).bind(this));
  
  this.then = this.promise.then.bind(this.promise);
  this.catch = this.promise.catch.bind(this.promise);
};

let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
let btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

let deferred = new Deferred();

let btn1OnClick = async () => {
  console.log("await button 2 clicked");
  await deferred;
  console.log("button 1 clicked");
};

let btn2OnClick = () => {
  deferred.resolve(true);
  console.log("button 2 clicked");
};

btn1.addEventListener("click", btn1OnClick);
btn2.addEventListener("click", btn2OnClick);
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
```